# to print a pattern using for loops

Tags: java

The pattern to be printed is this:(USING FOR LOOPS):it is a number pattern and the last column is the sum of the elements in each row:

```
1234  10  
2234  11  
3334  13  
4444  16
```

the pattern can be divided as

```
     1   234  10  
     22   34  11  
     333   4  13  
     4444     16
```

i have done this much:

```
public class pattern
{
void main(int n)
{
    int p = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i<= n; i++)
    {
        for(int j= 1;j<=i;j++) {
              System.out.print(i);
        }

         System.out.print("\n");               

    }

}
```

i have no idea how to proceed. **please help**.the code should be in **java**
thank you all for your suggestions.

Comment: what is the pattern ? why 4444  next to 3334

Comment: the  1234  2234  3334  4444

Comment: `1+2+3+4 =10` ok but why `4444` next `3334`

Comment: What's n? Is that supposed to determine the number of rows printed or does that affect the number of digits printed before the space?

Comment: n is the number of rows.

Comment: the vertical line is the sum of elements of each row

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code to print your pattern.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new pattern().main(4);

}
void main(int n) {
    int sum;
    for (int i = 1; i <=n; i++) {
        sum = 0;
        for (int j = 1; j <=n; j++) {
            if (i > j) {
                sum = sum + i;
                System.out.print(i);
                } else {
                sum = sum + j;
                System.out.print(j);
            }
        }
        System.out.print("   " + sum);
        System.out.print("\n");

    }
}
```

Comment: I think OP would probably learn more if you at least gave a break-down of the logic involved.